# How do Windows pscp options map to linux scp options?

Tags: linux, scp

I'd like to transfer my code that uses pscp from windows to linux, but I use some options, that I do not find the equivalent on linux.
How do these option map to scp?
-pw
-hostkey
-ls
-sftp
-batch (this is not the same as -b <batchfile>)

Thanks.

Comment: to transfer the password you have to use `sshpass`. Other parameters like hostkey etc do not have their own parameter in `scp` and might be configured in the `ssh` config. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need the equivalent on Linux? Are you also going to transfer from Linux back to Windows? You are using *PuTTY Secure Copy client* which is a very different program than the *OpenSSH scp* on Linux. So they don't share all the same options. But in the end they will all be using the SSH protocol to connect which will be compatible.

If you're struggling with a specific use case please describe your specific question and share your code.

If you want a more compatible solution, in terms of sharing the same options, you can also use `scp` on Windows hosts (which is also from OpenSSH and installed by default on modern Windows OSes).